# how to install manually pydev plugin 2.4.0 in eclipse on linux

Tags: pydev

I have installed eclipse in linux Red hat 4.4 X84_64 bit

I have to apply pydev plugin 2.4.0 in linux server in which i cannot access the internet and it is isoloated network

thats y i am unable to use Help->Install new software->by specifying the URL

Is any specfic pydev plugin 2.4.0 available for linux and what is procedure install plugin in linux

Thanks
guna

Answer (score 2):

You can install PyDev from a .zip file (mostly get it and extract contents to the dropins folder).

See: http://pydev.org/download.html for the proper links (http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html has more detailed instructions).